# How is this Producer & Consumer using pipes example able to prevent a deadlock?

Tags: c, pipe

I'm taking a look at a Solution Example for Producer & Consumer problem, using pipes.

And I do not understand how it is preventing a race condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


void producer(FILE *pipe_write_end)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    fprintf(pipe_write_end, "%d ", i);
  }
  fclose(pipe_write_end);
  exit(0);
}


void consumer(FILE *pipe_read_end)
{
  int n,k;

  while(1) {
    int n = fscanf(pipe_read_end, "%d", &k);
    if(n == 1) printf("consumer: got %d\n", k);
    else break;
  }
  fclose(pipe_read_end);
  exit(0);
}


int main()
{
  pid_t producer_id, consumer_id;
  int pd[2];
  FILE *pipe_write_end, *pipe_read_end;


  pipe(pd);
  pipe_read_end  = fdopen(pd[0], "r");
  pipe_write_end = fdopen(pd[1], "w");


  producer_id = fork();
  if(producer_id == 0) {
      fclose(pipe_read_end);
    producer(pipe_write_end);

  }

  consumer_id = fork();
  if(consumer_id == 0) {
    fclose(pipe_write_end);
    consumer(pipe_read_end);
  }

  fclose(pipe_read_end);
  fclose(pipe_write_end);
  wait(NULL);
  wait(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

My current thinking is that the `int n = fscanf(pipe_read_end, "%d", &k);` is waiting for the producer to close the file, but I don't understand how.

If 2 Child Processes are created, 1 to consume, 1 to Produce
- How is it able to automatically just produce without error?

Comment: Closing the write side of the pipe results in an end-of-file condition on the read side of the pipe. This is Pipe Fundamentals 101. As such, reading from the pipe fails, and `fscanf()` returns 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help @SamVarshavchik, I'm learning Pipes as we speak. For further clarification, Does that mean the fscanf will continue to return 0 until the consumer is finished? If the process is created at the same time, how does it know the consumer has finished its write. Thanks, in advance